# "operation was canceled" error message upon reading a single document

Tags: arangodb

I use golang's driver (github.com/arangodb/go-driver) to talk to Arangodb and this issue seems happening sporadically but often enough to be concerned about.

Request to read a single document fails with error "operation was canceled". Not much to add here, except that it might be a timeout.

```
var contributor model.Contributor
_, err = col.ReadDocument(ctx, id, &contributor)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("cannot read contributor %s document: %v", id, err)
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Can you read anything? The first thing to do is validate your context is correct and you can read something. Then focus on why this particular document from that collection is having issues.

Comment: First of all, this issue isn't permanent. It comes and goes. So, answering your question, yes, I can read from that collection, I can read this document, but once in a blue moon, my read request fails.

Second of all,  after a little bit more digging today, I found that it's not only a document read issue, same error pops up when making calls to get a collection.